# Getting distinct values from Django non-database list of objects

Tags: python, django

If I wanted to get a list of distinct values from a field called `season`in a Django model called `SeasonsNavOrder` in the database  I could use the following syntax:

```
seasonlist = SeasonsNavOrder.objects.values_list('season', flat=True).distinct()
```

But what if I want to get the distinct values from a list of non-database objects? In particular, i have the following list of objects:

```
[<bridge.models.Season object at 0x10226e290>, <bridge.models.Season object at 0x10226e350>, <bridge.models.Season object at 0x10226ef50>, <bridge.models.Season object at 0x10226eed0>]
```

Each object has a `season` property, and I would like to extract that into a list that would have the same structure as the list in the first case.

Obviously I could write a for loop to loop through the objects and append the `season` property into a list, but this seems inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

A set is by definition a collection of distinct objects.

```
your_list = [<bridge.models.Season object at 0x10226e290>, <bridge.models.Season object at 0x10226e350>, <bridge.models.Season object at 0x10226ef50>, <bridge.models.Season object at 0x10226eed0>]
your_set = Set(your_list)
```

`your_set` contains all the objects contained in `your_list` but without duplicates.